# Fixing data type conversion error in VBA code

Tags: ms-access, vba

Hello I am new to VBA and I was given this database where we have to copy values that are in the format shown in the excel file [on this website](https://sss2018.wixsite.com/accessquestion) and use the code shown below to arrange the values in respective columns and rows (because the format on the excel values is all over the place) and then insert it into an access table using a button. [this is what the access table looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3Yv3.png)

Now whenever I try to use the button, it gives me an error related to Rst!Date = FinalArray(i, 3), which is the data (basically dates) that would show up in the date column.

If I remove that line (or turn in into a comment momentarily) I am able to run the code properly, but of course the data corresponding to the date is missing. [see picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkUaf.png)
I know that there is a mistake on how the value for date is obtain but I just can pin point where or what the error is.
The error I get is: **"Run-time error '3427: Data Type conversion error"**

```
  Private Sub cmdCopy_Click()
  DoCmd.SetWarnings False
  DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE * FROM TblTempLabs"
   DoCmd.SetWarnings True
  Dim objData As New MSForms.DataObject
  Dim strText As String
  Dim i As Long
  Dim j As Long
  Dim k As Long
  Dim m As Long
  Dim ComponentNumber As Integer
  Dim Component(100, 2) As Long
  Dim LineArray(8000) As String
  Dim labname As Integer

  'get text from Clipboard
  objData.GetFromClipboard
  strText = objData.GetText()
  ' replace double empty lines with single
   StrLength = Len(strText)
   strText = Replace(strText, Chr(13) & Chr(10) & Chr(13) & Chr(10), Chr(13) & Chr(10))
   ' parse text string into individual lines
   Start = 1
  Lines = 0
  Do While Start < Len(strText)
marker = InStr(Start, strText, Chr(10))
If Asc(Mid(strText, Start, 1)) <> 32 Then
    LineArray(Lines) = Mid(strText, Start, marker - Start)
    Start = marker + 1
    Lines = Lines + 1
       Else: Start = marker + 1
       End If
  Loop
    For j = 0 To Lines - 1
    For m = 1 To 12
    LineArray(j) = Replace(LineArray(j), "  " & m & "/", " &" & m & "/")
   Next m
   LineArray(j) = LineArray(j) & "& "
   Next j
   Endarray = j
    'objData.SetText strSummary
   'objData.PutInClipboard
  ' determine column blocks and rows
   rownumber = 1
   block = 0
   Start = 1
   Dim RowPosition(40, 10) As Integer
  Dim FinalArray(6000, 20) As Variant
  For i = 0 To Lines
If Mid(LineArray(i), 1, 9) = "Component" Then
    Do While InStr(Start, LineArray(i), "&") <> 0
        RowPosition(block, 0) = i
        RowPosition(block, rownumber) = InStr(Start, LineArray(i), "&") + 1
        rownumber = rownumber + 1
        Start = InStr(Start, LineArray(i), "&") + 1
    Loop
    block = block + 1
    Start = 1
    rownumber = 1

End If
          Next i
  Test = 0
  final = 0
  For i = 0 To 40
  If RowPosition(i, 0) > 0 Then Test = Test + 1
  Next i
  Test = Test + 1
  Dim Labend As Integer
 For block = 0 To Test
      If block + 1 = Test Then
    Labend = Lines
    Else: Labend = RowPosition(block + 1, 0) - 1
End If
For i = RowPosition(block, 0) To Labend
    If Mid(LineArray(i), 1, 9) = "Component" Then
        Labnameposition = InStr(1, LineArray(i), "Latest") - 1
    End If
    If Mid(LineArray(i), 1, 9) <> "Component" Then
        strLabName = Mid(LineArray(i), 1, Labnameposition)
        strLabName = Replace(strLabName, " ", "")
        strRefRange = Mid(LineArray(i), Labnameposition + 1, RowPosition(block, 1) - Labnameposition - 2)
        strRefRange = Replace(strRefRange, " ", "")
        For j = 1 To 6
            DateStart = RowPosition(block, j)
            DateLength = RowPosition(block, j + 1) - RowPosition(block, j) - 1
            If DateLength > 0 Then
                strDate = Mid(LineArray(RowPosition(block, 0)), DateStart, DateLength)
                strDate = Replace(strDate, " ", "")
                strResult = Mid(LineArray(i), DateStart, DateLength - 2)
                strResult = Replace(strResult, " ", "")
                strDate = Replace(strDate, Chr(13), "")
                If Len(strResult) > 0 And strResult <> "NP" Then
                    FinalArray(final, 0) = strLabName
                    FinalArray(final, 1) = strRefRange
                    FinalArray(final, 2) = strResult
                    FinalArray(final, 3) = strDate
                    final = final + 1
                End If
            End If
        Next j
    End If
Next i
  Next block


   totaltest = 0
   Do While FinalArray(totaltest, 0) <> ""
    totaltest = totaltest + 1
   Loop

   Dim db As DAO.Database
   Dim Rst As DAO.Recordset
   Set db = CurrentDb
  Set Rst = db.OpenRecordset("TblTempLabs")
   For i = 0 To totaltest - 1
If InStr(1, FinalArray(i, 2), "(L)") > 0 Then
    FinalArray(i, 6) = "Low"
    FinalArray(i, 5) = Replace(FinalArray(i, 2), "(L)", "")
End If
If InStr(1, FinalArray(i, 2), "(H)") > 0 Then
    FinalArray(i, 6) = "High"
    FinalArray(i, 5) = Replace(FinalArray(i, 2), "(H)", "")
End If
If InStr(1, FinalArray(i, 2), "(A)") > 0 Then
    FinalArray(i, 6) = "Abnormal"
    FinalArray(i, 5) = Replace(FinalArray(i, 2), "(A)", "")
End If
If IsNumeric(FinalArray(i, 2)) = True Then
FinalArray(i, 5) = FinalArray(i, 2)
FinalArray(i, 6) = "Normal"
End If
If InStr(1, FinalArray(i, 2), ":") > 0 Then
FinalArray(i, 5) = Right(FinalArray(i, 2), Len(FinalArray(i, 2)) - InStr(1, FinalArray(i, 2), ":"))
FinalArray(i, 5) = Replace(FinalArray(i, 5), ".", "")
End If
If InStr(1, FinalArray(i, 2), "Negative") > 0 Or _
    InStr(1, FinalArray(i, 2), "neg") > 0 Or _
    InStr(1, FinalArray(i, 2), "nonreactive") > 0 Or _
    InStr(1, FinalArray(i, 2), "non-reactive") > 0 Then
FinalArray(i, 6) = "Negative"
End If
If InStr(1, FinalArray(i, 2), "Positive") > 0 Then FinalArray(i, 6) = "Positive"
If InStr(1, FinalArray(i, 2), "normal") > 0 Then FinalArray(i, 6) = "Normal"
If InStr(1, FinalArray(i, 2), "trace") > 0 Then FinalArray(i, 6) = "Trace"
If InStr(1, FinalArray(i, 0), "crp") > 0 And InStr(1, FinalArray(i, 2), "<") > 0 Then
FinalArray(i, 6) = "Negative"
End If
If InStr(1, FinalArray(i, 0), "rheumatoid") > 0 And InStr(1, FinalArray(i, 2), "<") > 0 Then
FinalArray(i, 6) = "Negative"
End If
If InStr(1, FinalArray(i, 0), "antinuclear") > 0 And Val(FinalArray(i, 5)) > 160 Then
FinalArray(i, 6) = "Positive"
End If
If InStr(1, FinalArray(i, 2), "ANAtiter:greater") > 0 Then
FinalArray(i, 5) = 640
FinalArray(i, 6) = "Positive"
End If
If InStr(1, FinalArray(i, 2), "nocryo") > 0 Then FinalArray(i, 6) = "Negative"
If (InStr(1, FinalArray(i, 0), "estimatedglom") > 0 Or _
InStr(1, FinalArray(i, 0), "estGFR") > 0) And _
InStr(1, FinalArray(i, 2), ">") > 0 Then
FinalArray(i, 6) = "Normal"
End If
       Rst.AddNew
      Rst!Test = FinalArray(i, 0)
      Rst!refrange = FinalArray(i, 1)
      Rst!ResultComment = FinalArray(i, 2)
      Rst!Date = FinalArray(i, 3)
      If (FinalArray(i, 5)) = Empty Or Not IsNumeric(FinalArray(i, 5)) Then
      Rst!ResultNumeric = Empty
      Else: Rst!ResultNumeric = CDec(FinalArray(i, 5))
      End If
      Rst!ResultBoolean = FinalArray(i, 6)
      Rst!ID = Me.Text55
      Rst.Update
  Next i
 Dim str As String
 Rst.MoveFirst
Do While Not Rst.EOF
          str = Rst!Test
              Select Case str

                  Case ""
                      Rst.Edit
                      Rst!Test = "ESR"
                      Rst.Update
                       str = ""
                  Case Else
                 str = ""
             End Select
         Rst.MoveNext
      Loop
 Rst.Close
 Set db = Nothing
 Me.Child40.Requery
 End Sub
```

Comment: the error is Run-Time error '3421': Data type conversion error.

Comment: It says Units String and it highlights:  If (FinalArray(i, 5)) = Empty Or Not IsNumeric(FinalArray(i, 5)) Then Rst!ResultNumeric = Empty

Comment: This is what I get, Debug.Print FinalArray(i, 3), TypeName(FinalArray(i, 3)), IsDate(FinalArray(i, 3))
Units         String        False                                                                                              Now since  FinalArray(final, 3) = strDate                                                                            if I print strDate it prints an actual date

Comment: if `Debug.Print FinalArray(i, 3)` is returning "Units", then that explains your error - that is NOT a date. Check your source data line - right after `strDate = Mid(LineArray(RowPosition(block, 0)), DateStart, DateLength)` use a `Debug.print strDate`

Answer (score 0):

Just convert it from a string to a date, VBA and VB usually takes care of casting but in some cases (eg working with a Recordset) you have to explicitly cast, eg:

```
Rst!Date = CDate(FinalArray(i, 3))
```

Make sure the date is the same format as the region the database is set, ie dd/mm/yyyy, or mm/dd/yyyy.